# How to decide whether a method should belong to which class?

Tags: class, oop, methods

I have 3 classes:

- `product`
- `product_list`
- and `customer`

The `product_list` class has an array list, which stores `product` objects.

If I have a `viewProduct` method, it should belong to `customer` class or `product_list` class?

With my own concept, a `viewProduct` method should belong to `customer` class, because customer views products. But in code-wise, how a method in `customer` class gets data from `product_list` class?

Answer (score 1):

A class is a data structure, bound together with the algorithms working on it.

*Thus, if you decide where to put a method, the rule of thumb is this: select the class, on whose data structures it works the most. If you do it well, it should not even access the data members of other classes directly, only their methods.*

Also from the name of the method is it visible, that you are right, that `viewProduct` should belong to `customer`: if it would belong to a `product`, then the `viewProduct` name would be redundant. Then a `view` name would be better.

You example does not say anything, how `customer`s relate to specific `product`s. For example, if you would develop a webshop, then the `customer`s would likely choose a product from a list which your controllers generated for them.

Your specification lacks the mechanism, how `customer`s relate to products. Think on it, and you will know the answer.